# Square columns in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a grid of squares to provide some navigation features.

Squares meaning that the width and height of the colored areas will be equal.

I have it working with js, but I would prefer a CSS only solution. I'm working with bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: lightgray"></div>
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: lightgreen"></div>
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: lightgray"></div>
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: lightgreen"></div>
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: lightgray"></div>
    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: lightgreen"></div>
  </div>
</div>

var divs = $(".row > div");
var width = divs.width();
divs.height(width)
```

How can I achieve this with css only?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include the boostrap css. `.container` will set an exact width and `.col-xs-4` will set each div 1/3rd of that width.  `.container` width is a fixed width and will be wider than your body width of 200px. You should only have 12 cols per row (so 3x col-xs-4).  You don't need the jquery as the width will already be known.

Comment: Any CSS solution will rely on `display:flex`.  And if you're going to go that route you might as well take the plunge to Bootstrap 4 as you can make use of baked-in classes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this trick: https://mademyday.de/height-equals-width-with-pure-css/

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/65mhv1cp/

basically, you can add a class to your squares, call it `square`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 square" style="background-color: lightgray"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 square" style="background-color: lightgreen"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 square" style="background-color: lightgray"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 square" style="background-color: lightgreen"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 square" style="background-color: lightgray"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 square" style="background-color: lightgreen"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS would be:

```
.square:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
```

Read more in the link to understand how/why this works.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
             
            }
            .gray {
              background-color: lightgray;
            }
            .green {
              background-color: lightgreen;
            }
        </style>
        
        <script>
            function size(){
                
                var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('blockBox');
                var divsWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('blockBox')[0].offsetWidth;

                for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                    divs[i].style.height= divsWidth+'px';
                }
                
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="size();">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 gray blockBox">1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 green blockBox">2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 gray blockBox">3</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 green blockBox">4</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 gray blockBox">5</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 green blockBox">6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```